# How to Control Fragment in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
public class NewMappingFragment extends Fragment{

    ...

    public void setMyPlaceInMap(){
            map =  ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(locationNState.getLocation().getLatitude(), locationNState.getLocation().getLongitude()), 17 ));
     }
}
```

Hi, In my app there's a function named setMyPlaceInMap in "NewMappingFragment" Fragment.

when run this app, it returns null pointexception at

```
 map =  ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

this line...

i found that getFragmentManager can be used in activity level.

then what function is okay  to manage fragment in fragment.???

p.s : R.id.map <- this is Fragment for GoogleMaps v2

Comment: U have to call findViewById from fragmnts View object. Post your code where you call this method

Comment: If R.id.mao fragment is added to NewMappingFragment, then it has parent-child relationship. You need to use getChildFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager().